# Is possible to set a date when converting with pandas.to_datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array([(b'03:35:05.397191'),
    (b'03:35:06.184700'),
    (b'03:35:08.642503'), ...,
    (b'05:47:15.285806'),
    (b'05:47:20.189460'),
    (b'05:47:30.598514')],
    dtype=[('Date', 'S15')])
```

I want to convert it into a dataframe, using `to_datetime`. I could do that by simply doing this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( array )
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime( df['Date'].str.decode("utf-8") )

>>> df.Date
0      2018-03-07 03:35:05.397191
1      2018-03-07 03:35:06.184700
2      2018-03-07 03:35:08.642503
3      2018-03-07 03:35:09.155030
4      2018-03-07 03:35:09.300029
5      2018-03-07 03:35:09.303031
```

The problem is that it automatically sets the date as today. Is it possible to set the date as a different day, for example, 2015-01-25?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `pd.to_datetime`, use `pd.to_timedelta` and add a date.

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.Date.str.decode("utf-8")) + pd.to_datetime('2017-03-15')

0   2017-03-15 03:35:05.397191
1   2017-03-15 03:35:06.184700
2   2017-03-15 03:35:08.642503
3   2017-03-15 05:47:15.285806
4   2017-03-15 05:47:20.189460
5   2017-03-15 05:47:30.598514
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know there's ```to_timedelta``` method. I've learned something useful today thanks to you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime( df['Date'].str.decode("utf-8") ).apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=2015, month=1, day=25))
```

Incorporating @Wen's solution for correctness :)

Comment: Nice usage.  for further reference  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.replace.html

Comment: @Connor John Thank you for the answer. But when I tried it, I got this error: ```TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'year'```

Comment: are you copying the full line of code? datetime.replace() takes year as a param. I'm guessing it's being applied to a string

Comment: @maynull `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.decode("utf-8")).apply(lambda x : x.replace(year=2015, month=1, day=25))`, you need apply here

Comment: @Wen that's what I was missing. Thanks!  this is what you need

Comment: Thank you for helping me, both of you!

Comment: @maynull ummm adding a way for fix your date :-)

Answer (score 1):

you could create a string with complete date-time and parse, like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( array )
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime( '20150125 ' + df['Date'].str.decode("utf-8") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, seems like it work :-)

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.decode("utf-8"))-(pd.to_datetime('today')-pd.to_datetime('2015-01-25'))
Out[376]: 
0   2015-01-25 03:35:05.397191
1   2015-01-25 03:35:06.184700
2   2015-01-25 03:35:08.642503
3   2015-01-25 05:47:15.285806
4   2015-01-25 05:47:20.189460
5   2015-01-25 05:47:30.598514
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```